# Normal invariants

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, surgery-theory

I am having a hard time finding examples of computations of normal invariants of surgery theory (or more generally the set of homotopy classes of maps $[X,G/O]$). Does anybody have good references?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many examples of computations of $[M,G/O]$ appear in papers which apply surgery theory. Here are some examples:

- [Brumfiel](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/brumfiel.pdf) did the complex projective spaces $\mathbb{C}P^n$.
- [Land](http://markus-land.de/app/download/2771195/Normal+invariants.pdf) did the complex projective space $\mathbb{C}P^2$.
- [Kirby-Siebenmann](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/ks.pdf) did high-dimensional tori in Appendix V.B.
- [Crowley](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10711-010-9513-8) did products of spheres $S^p \times S^q$ for $p,q \geq 2$ and $p+q \geq 5$.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately I do not know any good references for detailed computations, but let me point out that the rational picture is rather simple: we have $$G/O \sim_{\mathbb Q} BO \sim_{\mathbb Q} = \prod_{i \geq 1} K(\mathbb Q,4i)$$ and thus
$$ [M,G/O] \sim_{\mathbb Q} \prod_{i \geq 1} H^{4i}(M;\mathbb Q)$$
In particular, $\mathcal N(S^n)$ is finite if $n \not\equiv 0 \ (\text{mod} \ 4)$, and infinite cyclic if $n \equiv 0 \ (\text{mod} \ 4)$, in line with the analogous statement for the $L$-groups of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Good to point out that we know the homotopy groups of $G/Top$, the surgery exact sequence, and we know that $Top/O$ has homotopy groups (maybe we need above dimension 4) in bijection with oriented exotic spheres. So from the sequence $Top/O \rightarrow G/O \rightarrow G/Top$ we see that essentially the normal invariants break up into components coming from exotic spheres and components coming from the surgery obstructions (corresponding to Milnor and Kervaire manifolds). Upon rationalization this gives what you have.

Comment: Sorry I meant the surgery groups not the surgery exact sequence.

Answer (score 4):

If you want specifically low-dimensional calculations, the Kirby-Taylor article [A survey of 4-manifolds through the eyes of surgery](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9803101) does this for 4-manifolds. The discussion highlights the difference between the topological and smooth (= PL in this dimension) cases.